# how to display public users and friend users

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM users as us  
          right join following as fl
              on us.id_user = fl.user1_id 
          WHERE us.id_user !='$id_user_circle'  
            AND fl.user1_id !='$id_user_circle'";
```

only 2 users appear in public

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a left join?

So you have two records in 'following' that also have records in 'users' and  whose id's are not $id_user_circle - what do you expect to see?   Also you probably do not need the AND since you have the 'ON'matching the user_ids's.  Note RIGHT JOIN means take all the records from 'following' and then the matches from users.

Answer (score 0):

good luck !!
$query="SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT *  FROM users  WHERE 
id_user !='$id_user_circle' 
) AS A
right JOIN 
( SELECT *  FROM following WHERE 
 user1_id !='$id_user_circle'
) AS A
on A.id_user = B.user1_id";